# GroupByKey vs Join performance in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD like `(id, (val1, val2))`. I want to normalize the val2 values for each id by dividing by sum of all val2 for that particular id. So my output should look like `(id, (val1, val2normalized))`

There are 2 ways of doing this

1. Do a `groupByKey` on id followed by normalizing the value using `mapValues`.
2. Do a `reduceByKey` to get RDD like `(id, val2sum)` and join this RDD with original RDD to get `(id, ((val1, val2), val2sum))` followed by `mapValues`to normalize.

Which one should be chosen?

Answer (score 1):

If you limit yourself to:

- `RDD` API.
- `groupByKey` + `mapValues` vs. `reduceByKey` + `join`

the former one will be preferred. Since `RDD.join` is implemented using `cogroup` the cost of the latter strategy can be only higher than `groupByKey` (`cogroup` on the unreduced `RDD` will be equivalent to `groupByKey`, but you additionally need a full shuffle for `reduceByKey`). Please keep in mind, that if groups are to large, neither solution will be feasible.

This however might not be the optimal choice. Depending on the size of each group and the total number of groups, you might be able to achieve much better performance using [broadcast join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34053302/10465355).

At the same time `DataFrame` API comes with significantly improved shuffle internals and can automatically apply some optimizations, including broadcast joins.

Comment: The size of each group is less than 50. DataFrame won't be feasible in my case because I also need to add some (val1, 0) pairs for val1's which are not present in the dataset for each id, which is not possible in DataFrame because after groupBy("id") you can only do simple aggregations.