# Filtering dataframes conditioned on multiple columns, with different conditions depending on column values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter a dataframe conditioned on multiple columns. The issue is that the condition changes with the column value.

For example, I have the following raw dataset.

```
df_assets = pd.DataFrame(
    {'asset_id': ['10092', '39883', '82883', '28883', '09093', '27817', '38261', '28372', '38472', '39738'],
     'asset_type' :['laptop', 'mousepad', 'mouse', 'pen', 'pen', 'monitor', 'wire', 'laptop', 'keyboard', 'mouse'],
     'quantity': [3, 12, 12, 10, 2, 0, 21, 0, 10, 16],
     'assigned': ['susan', 'jane', 'amy', 'ben', 'donald', 'evan', 'chris', 'fred', 'henry', 'george']
    })
```

```
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
|asset_id|asset_type|assigned|quantity|
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
|   10092|    laptop|   susan|     3.0|
|   39883|  mousepad|    jane|    12.0|
|   82883|     mouse|     amy|    12.0|
|   28883|       pen|     ben|    10.0|
|   09093|       pen|  donald|     2.0|
|   27817|   monitor|    evan|     0.0|
|   38261|      wire|   chris|    21.0|
|   28372|    laptop|    fred|     0.0|
|   38472|  keyboard|   henry|    10.0|
|   39738|     mouse|  george|    16.0|
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
```

I would like to apply a filter that return rows that have a quantity higher than stated in the following dictionary, (i.e. keyboards with quantity >= 10, wire with quantity >= 10, laptop with quantity >= 1 etc). I also would like to return  rows that do not contain the asset type specified in the dictionary.

```
d = {'keyboard': 10, 'wire': 20, 'laptop': 1, 'mouse': 15, 'monitor': 1}
```

The output should be

```
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
|asset_id|asset_type|assigned|quantity|
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
|   10092|    laptop|   susan|     3.0|
|   38261|      wire|   chris|    21.0|
|   39738|     mouse|  george|    16.0|
|   38472|  keyboard|   henry|    10.0|
|   39883|  mousepad|    jane|    12.0|
|   28883|       pen|     ben|    10.0|
|   09093|       pen|  donald|     2.0|
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
```

Is there an elegant way to do this? I implemented the above by filtering and creating a dataframe for each item in the dictionary and appending to final dataframe.

```
count = 0
for k, v in d.items():
    sdf_filter = sdf_assets.filter( (f.col('asset_type') == k) & (f.col('quantity') >= v) )
    if count != 0:
        sdf_thresholded = sdf_thresholded.union(sdf_filter)
    else:
        sdf_thresholded = sdf_filter
    count += 1

sdf_result_test = sdf_thresholded.union(sdf_assets.filter(~f.col('asset_type').isin(d.keys())))
```

I wrote everything in PySpark because the full dataset has many entries, but I would appreciate any solution in python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your dictionary `d` into a spark DataFrame:

```python
d = {'keyboard': 10, 'wire': 20, 'laptop': 1, 'mouse': 15, 'monitor': 1}
d = spark.createDataFrame(d.items(), ["asset_type", "min_quantity"])
d.show()
#+----------+------------+
#|asset_type|min_quantity|
#+----------+------------+
#|    laptop|           1|
#|      wire|          20|
#|     mouse|          15|
#|   monitor|           1|
#|  keyboard|          10|
#+----------+------------+
```

Now you can LEFT join this with you `df_assets` spark DataFrame, and use `where` to filter the rows according to your conditions. Since `d` is small, you can use a [`broadcast` join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053302/pyspark-and-broadcast-join-example) for improved performance.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast 

# first convert from pandas DataFrame to spark DataFrame
df_assets = spark.createDataFrame(df_assets)

# left join with d
df_assets.join(broadcast(d), on="asset_type", how="left")\
    .where("min_quantity IS NULL or quantity >= min_quantity")\
    .select("asset_id", "asset_type", "assigned", "quantity")\
    .show()
#+--------+----------+--------+--------+
#|asset_id|asset_type|assigned|quantity|
#+--------+----------+--------+--------+
#|   10092|    laptop|   susan|       3|
#|   39883|  mousepad|    jane|      12|
#|   28883|       pen|     ben|      10|
#|   09093|       pen|  donald|       2|
#|   38261|      wire|   chris|      21|
#|   38472|  keyboard|   henry|      10|
#|   39738|     mouse|  george|      16|
#+--------+----------+--------+--------+
```