# Match DataFrame column value against another DataFrame column and count hits

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I've two Spark DataFrames. Where `df1` contains addresses and `df2` streetnames, cities, regions etc.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["001", "Luc  Krier","2363  Ryan Road, Long Lake South Dakota","2363RyanRoad,LongLakeSouthDakota"],
  ["002", "Jeanny  Thorn","2263 Patton Lane Raleigh North Carolina","2263PattonLaneRaleighNorthCarolina"],
  ["003", "Teddy E Beecher","2839 Hartland Avenue Fond Du Lac Wisconsin","2839HartlandAvenueFondDuLacWisconsin"],
  ["004", "Philippe  Schauss","1 Im Oberdorf Allemagne","1ImOberdorfAllemagne"],
 ["005", "Meindert I Tholen","Hagedoornweg 138 Amsterdam","Hagedoornweg138Amsterdam"]
]).toDF("id","name","address1", "address2")

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
 ["US","Amsterdam"],
 ["US","SouthDakota"],
 ["LU","Allemagne"],
 ["FR","Allemagne"],
 ["NL","Amsterdam"],
 ["NL","Rotterdam"],
 ["US","Wisconsin"],
 ["AU","Wisconsin"],
 ["AU","Hartland"]
]).toDF("cc","point")
```

I want to check if df1['address2'] contains any of the values from df2['point'] and the expected result is (fictitious and not in accordance with the dataframe examples) a new column `cc` with values like:

```
('US':1)
('US':2)('NL':1)
('US':3)('FR':1)('LU':1)
('NL':1)
```

returns `cc` from `df2['cc']` and the number of matches. An address can hit on multiple values from `df2`. Sorted by number of matches (highest first)

Comment: how is your table size? you are going to create a cross join, which is really bad in terms of performance.

Comment: @Steven df1 approx. 25.000.000 and df2 approx 12.000.000

Comment: is it possible to split address2 in several words ? using the capital letters for example.

Comment: @Steven Yes that's possible. I removed the spaces in both DataFrames but that can be changed. So 'SouthDakota' in df2 is original 'South Dakota'

Comment: Is city always the last part of your address1 ? If so maybe try to extract the city out of address1 using regex, add to a new column and join based on that.

Comment: @RudyVerboven Unfortunately that is not the case. the address field is free format. I have to search the whole string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a "conditional" join. Bet be aware, like [@Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5013752/steven) mentioned in his comment, this will create a cross-join. Performance wise this will not be your best option. But just know that what you try to achieve is possible when you don't take performance into account.

```
df_join = df1.join(df2, df1.address2.contains(df2.point), how='left')
result = df_join
         .groupBy('id','name','address1', 'cc').count()
         .select('id', 'name', 'address1', f.concat(f.lit("'"), f.col("cc"), f.lit("':"), f.col("count")).alias('cc'))
         .groupBy('id','name','address1').agg(f.concat_ws("", f.collect_list(f.col("cc"))).alias('cc'))
```

What may help is that you broadcast df2 (the smallest one).

[PySpark and broadcast join example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053302/pyspark-and-broadcast-join-example)

Comment: This does not give me the desired output e.g. `('US':3)('FR':1)('LU':1)`